# Django authenticate() user is returning None

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have just implemented Facebook login/signup on my site. When a user logs in, I check *(via AJAX call)* if I already have her *Facebook UserID* and *email* in my **myModel**. If yes the user is logged in with a **make_password(** password **)** I internally created for them else user is created.

My code:

```
#Get Facebook detail, through AJAX
userEmail = request.POST['email']
userID = request.POST['userID']
userName = request.POST['username'].replace(" ", "")

#Check if the user already exist.
try:
   new_user = myModel.objects.get(email = userEmail, fb_id = userID)
except myModel.DoesNotExist:
   new_user = None

if new_user is not None:
    user = authenticate(username = new_user.username, password = "internal")
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse("User Authenticated Successfully")
    return HttpResponse("User NOT Authenticated!")

#Create and save user here...
pwd = make_password("internal")
new_user = myModel(email=userEmail, fb_id=userID, username=userName, password=pwd)
new_user.save()

#Create and save this user in Django **User** model.
created_user = User.objects.created_user(userName, userEmail, pwd)
created_user.save()
return HttpResponse("User created successfully!")
```

But user is always **None** for an existing user even if I manually (hard coded) usernames and passwords that works.

Comment: Did you checked if userEmail, userID and userName are not empty?

Comment: They are not empty. I have even hard coded valid `username` and `password` but still not working.

Comment: What is the error when you remove the try except around the new_user query?

Comment: try this :
user = authenticate(username = new_user.username, password = newuser.password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `make_password` is the one from django.contrib.auth, then you are hashing the password twice. You convert `pwd` to a hash when you call that function, but then you pass it into `create_user` which hashes it again. Either use the normal `User.objects.create()` when creating the user, or pass the raw string "internal" to `create_user`.